# Terminal always opens empty

Tags: command-line, screen

recently every terminal I open is totally empty, with active cursor but no directory.
To keep going I always must press CTRL + C, like I have to kill process or something.

I assume it has to do with my recent installation of Vscode.
But if I close all programs and then open a terminal it is still empty.
even a fresh reboot doesn't help.

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Maybe you got some hints to solve it.

Comment: If there's a process running any time you invoke an interactive shell, it's most likely started via one of the shell's initialization files - for bash, those would be `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bash.bashrc` and so on. So check those first.

Comment: To debug your `~/.bashrc`, _temporarily_ put `set  -x` at the beginning. Logout/login, or just invoke it with `. ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I solved it, the was an "ng completion script" running in the ~/.bashrc .
Thanks for your help.